# A single word name for the "I don't know" gesture

Tags: single-word-requests, gestures

I have no idea if it is country specific, but in our country if someone doesn't know something he or she would put their lower lip forward.

However, I cannot find  a name for this lip gesture. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It apparently **is** country(region, language, culture)-specific. The pouting gesture does not signify ignorance in Anglophone discourse; that's what the _shrug_ is for. Shrugging is a movement of the shoulders, not the lip, accompanied by raised eyebrows; it signifies ignorance and/or lack of interest.

Comment: @JohnLawler, while I agree that a pout doesn't indicate ignorance, I disagree with the suggestion that the lip is not involved in a "shrug" expression in Anglophone discourse. My American friends and family often, if not always, accompany the shoulder and eyebrow movement with a particular lip movement -- though not a pout, maybe more of a pursing expression. (There is also a hand movement, palms rotating upward, in the full expression.)

Comment: @pingpongi, what country are you thinking of, where this gesture is used?

Comment: Does the gesture you're thinking of look the same as a "lip shrug"? See #1 at http://howtobeisraeli.blogspot.com/2009/12/how-to-shrug-like-israeli-quick-and.html (This gesture may not be universal but it is recognizable to us Americans.)

Comment: One word? Easy.  Iunno

Comment: LarsH is close, but not there yet. However that gesture seems to be more polite of the two.

Comment: Based on your description, all I can imagine are my various ex-girlfriends pouting.  I have words for them, but probably not what you're looking for.

Comment: A single word name for the "I don't know" gesture: "Dunno!"

Answer (score 9):

The ***Gallic shrug*** includes both the moue (facial gesture) along with the shoulder shrug

"Raise your shoulders; hold up your hands, palms out; stick out your lower lip; raise your eyebrows;"

http://french.about.com/library/weekly/aa020901g.htm

Comment: Ha, interesting! But it's not a "single word" :)

Comment: But it would definitely be a fun exercise to document the gestures conveying ignorance across various cultures.

Comment: the single word the OP asked for, just the lip movement, is the "moue" bit...

Comment: The moue alone seems to admit to other nonverbal messages--dislike, disgust, disapproval. Or so I understand.

Comment: But a *moue* is essentially a pout, and it also indicates annoyance, not ignorance.

Comment: I'll add a mini-rant about single word requests. We all want them. Sometimes they are not to be had, at least not without resorting to language far outside common usage. It seems to me that most questioners are seeking accurate terms and correct usage that can be widely understood. Sometimes, a more common phrase serves better than a much less common single word.

Comment: @GMB: I agree. My first comment was made tongue-in-cheek. Mini-rant well taken.

Comment: @JimiOke: I got that. No problem.

Answer (score 5):

The word for this gesture is *pout*. In the US and other anglophone nations, pouting usually indicates annoyance or exasperation. So, I wouldn't call this the "I-don't-know" gesture (words like *shrug*, etc, come to mind for this), but *pout* is the word you are looking for here.

> **pout**: push one’s lips or one’s bottom lip forward as an expression of petulant annoyance or in order to make oneself look sexually attractive <sup>[NOAD](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/pout?q=pout)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

**[to pout:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Pout)** may come close to what you are looking for:

> To protrude the lips in an expression of displeasure or sulkiness.
>
> To project or protrude.

Comment: I think this is a good answer (a +1 from me anyway) but with a problem, in that *pout* would imply to many readers such a gesture being used as a sullen or exasperated gesture (I'd expect a shrug to indicate someone didn't know something). But then, that is a matter of the cultural meaning of the gesture, rather than the word being inappropriate for the gesture. I'd suggest the querent accept this answer, but also make it clear how it would be interpretted; "their pout suggested they didn't know" or similar.

Comment: @JonHanna: To me, the cultural meaning of the pouting gesture (sulkiness) is so closely bound into the word 'pout' that if someone needed to communicate a lip movement signifying ignorance, I would feel like 'pout' was the wrong word. Even using it with modification, e.g. "He pouted to show his ignorance," would be very awkward and easily misunderstood.

Answer (score 2):

Protruding lower lip out normally is accompanied with lifting of both eyebrows and symbolises informal and carefree gesture implying "no clue". It is not a polite or respectful gesture.

Comment: Yeah you nailed it. I think you and I are on the same line here: http://o.quizlet.com/vUmtEtrnoq-ZybXUJIdhaw_m.jpg